# Reserved keyword in controller action - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, routing, uicomponent

I am working on an admin grid concept. I found one [github](https://github.com/arvind07/productsgrid_magento2) source code and analyzed that one.

While I found the URL is different from the declaration in the UI component [layout](https://github.com/arvind07/productsgrid_magento2/blob/master/Webspeaks/ProductsGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/ws_contacts_listing.xml#L23).

```
<item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
```

`*/*` is mean **current** frontname and action path, but I could not find `New.php` in controller path but instead `NewAction.php` file is present.

So I am confused. How is this automatically mapping to `NewAction.php` like factory method in Model?

can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are some words that you cannot use for class names.
Basically the reserved php words like `new`, `public`, `static`, ...

To overcome this and still allow these words in the urls Magento adds the suffix `Action` when the class is autoloaded.
This means that `new` maps to `NewAction.php`, `public` to `PublicAction.php`.

[You can find in the class `\Magento\Framework\App\Router\ActionList` (2.3 branch)](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php#L28) the list of words that have this behavior.

```
protected $reservedWords = [
    'abstract', 'and', 'array', 'as', 'break', 'callable', 'case', 'catch', 'class', 'clone', 'const',
    'continue', 'declare', 'default', 'die', 'do', 'echo', 'else', 'elseif', 'empty', 'enddeclare',
    'endfor', 'endforeach', 'endif', 'endswitch', 'endwhile', 'eval', 'exit', 'extends', 'final',
    'for', 'foreach', 'function', 'global', 'goto', 'if', 'implements', 'include', 'instanceof',
    'insteadof','interface', 'isset', 'list', 'namespace', 'new', 'or', 'print', 'private', 'protected',
    'public', 'require', 'return', 'static', 'switch', 'throw', 'trait', 'try', 'unset', 'use', 'var',
    'while', 'xor',
];
```

[and here is the code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/ActionList.php#L91) that changes `new` to `NewAction`.

Comment: great explanation!

Comment: @Marius 2nd link is outdated.