# Magento 2.1: Letter Case for Controller Actions URL Route

Tags: magento2, module, magento-2.1, controllers

I tried to create a custom payment gateway by creating a custom module based on Paypal module, specically [Paypal Express Checkout](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Controller/Express).

I was able to replicate the route for controller actions: Start, Return, Cancel, and PlaceHolder. I tried to create my own controller action (let's say "NotificationHandler") by copy the Start action, rename the class name, and remove everything in execute() and put echo "hello world";. For some reason, I ran into some weird issue where it expects me to have the first letter of the action to be capital letter (..\ {routeID}\ {controllername}\ **Notificationhandler**). The site will throw error 404 if I put in the lower case (..\ {routeID}\ {controllername}\ **notificationhandler**).

Here are some follow up questions:

1. Is there some config file that determine the exact case of the controller action URL?
2. Why is it that the ReturnAction use the URL ...{routeId}{controllername}\return instead of ...{routeId}{controllername}\returnaction

Thank you,

Comment: your 2nd question answer is here http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124416/36463

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for sharing the post. Any idea regarding the action route require to be upper case on the first letter or else it throws 404?

Comment: I hope you can declare controller class Notificationhandler.php not notificationhandler.php. if not please change. show your controller may be it is helpful to debug

Comment: Yes, it's Notificationhandler.php, the class name is also Notificationhandler. My confusion is that why is it that I have Start.php with class name Start and I was able to access the controller action via ... {route ID} \ {controller name} \start and not getting 404 error (I can also use ... {route ID} \ {controller name}\Start as well).

Comment: check namespace and class name in Notificationhandler.php. please  attach controller code in your question and show your module tree structure.

Comment: The namespace and class name looks good to me. Are they supposed to have any affect on whether the action name will have the first letter capitalized? If so, how come Paypal's actions support both upper and lower case for the first letter despite the class name has it capitalized? I will post the code in my question later today. Thank you again for reaching out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45370/discussion-between-frostshoxx-and-bilal-usean).

Comment: Good morning.. I just to follow up on the status. For some weird reason after I upgrade Magento to 2.1.1, it no longer has the issue with the URL. I was able to use lowercase \notificationhandler now.

Answer (score 0):

After I upgrade Magento to version 2.1.1, the issue seems to go away. I was able to access the URL for the action in both upper and lowercase for the first letter.