# Is "/catalog" a reserved route in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I expected this to be simple, but it seems linking to a category named "catalog" isn't as straight forward as I expected.

I've got a category structure similar to the following:

```
- Default Category
    - Catalog
        - Mens
        - Womens
          ...
```

#### Linking to a child category works

```
/catalog/mens
```

#### ...but linking to a category called "catalog" doesn't

This will redirect me to the home page.

```
/catalog
```

#### Renaming "catalog" to "catalog2" works...

```
/catalog2
```

## The Question

Does this mean `/catalog` is a reserved route in Magento 2?

Comment: Nope https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124405/reserved-keyword-in-controller-action-magento-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah This is reserved rout path which you are not supposed to use.

you can refer the core module to check any path.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/frontend/routes.xml
```

check this file where rout is defined for the catalog module.